# Making an ActiveRecord query sleep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, asynchronous

I want to force an expensive activerecord database query to test whether a gem I installed, which makes AR queries asynchronous, actually works. I know that in SQL you can do something like `SELECT sleep(5);` Is there a way to do this through ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SQL implementation supports the "sleep" command, you can force ActiveRecord to execute it (and any other arbitrary SQL) like so:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT sleep(5);')
```